# How to overload [] for const object, so that the value assignment would not result in a compilation error

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I need to overload [] operator for non-const and const objects. For non-const objects, it should be possible to read and assign values. For const objects, it should be possible to read values, but value assignment should not affect the element. At the same time, the code should be compilable.

The declarations, that I created:

```
int &operator[](int element_index);
const int &operator[](int element_index) const;
```

The problem with this kind of declarations is, that the following code:

```
const MyObject some_object(); 
some_object[1] = 100;
```

results in a compilation error: "assignment of read-only location" (some_object[1] exists and can be read). The desired behavior is that there would be no compilation error. I tried to find a way to return a copy of an element, but unfortunately, I didn’t find a combination that would work.

Comment: Unclear: what do you expect the effect of `some_object[1] = 100;` to be when run (if there was no compilation error)? Note that modifying an object declared as `const` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Why don't you want a compiler error?  It goes against the rule of least surprise to be able to modify a const object.

Comment: Also watch out for vexing parse: `const MyObject some_object();` is an accidental function declaration, not a variable definition.

Comment: this smells like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you think you need to allow `some_object[1] = 100;` when it is not doing what one would expect? Even worse, `some_non_const_object[1] = 100;` looks the same but does something completely different.

Comment: It's a requirement for an assignment for my C++ classes so that it would be possible to run unit test afterward (for grading).

Comment: sorry I dont buy that. You shouldnt break stuff that works well in such a horrible way, just to make a unit test work. I´d rather say that you need to fix the test. A test that tries to assign to a const should only succeed if the assignment fails....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an ugly thing to do - as it leads to unmaintainable client code where assignments have no affect - but it is possible to orchestrate.  You need to return something from the non-`const` indexing operator that you can assign to without affecting the container.  Below, the `const` indexing operator returns `DummyInt` by value, and the assignment therein is a `const` function (so you can call it on the temporary returned without storing it to a named variable) that does nothing.  It also captures the integer value from the container and provides an `operator int() const` function to access it.

Available to edit/run on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d87ae784df1ebf9):

```
#include <iostream>

struct C
{
    struct DummyInt
    {
        int n_;
        operator int() const { return n_; }
        const DummyInt& operator=(int) const { return *this; }
    };

    DummyInt operator[](int n) const { return DummyInt{a_[n]}; }

    int& operator[](int n) { return a_[n]; }
    int a_[3];
};

int main()
{
    const C c{ 4, 5, 6 };
    c[1] = 2;
    for (auto x : c.a_) std::cout << x << '\n';

    C c2{ 7, 8, 9 };
    c2[1] = 2;
    for (auto x : c2.a_) std::cout << x << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
4
5
6
7
2
9
```

Comment: Why not simply have `operator[](int n)const` return `int` by copy? Wouldn't that have the same effects?

Comment: @MooingDuck: if it returns a copy of an `int` by value, you can't assign to it without a compiler error.

Comment: hesitating to upvote, because it is correct, but nobody should write code like that :P

Comment: @user463035818: I can relate!  I hesistated to answer, but "don't do it" is kinda boring and it's technically mildly interesting to know how you can.